# Set the List item row height in xml has no effect

Tags: android, xml

I try to set the list item row height in xml files.For example, I have a listView and a corresponding listAdapter, this adapter inflate a view from a xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView 
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_right"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="#f96f00"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:lines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

However this `60dp` has no effect, no matter how much this height you have set the inflated row view has a fixed height. When I adjust the textview inside the layout, the row height has changed. Why this happen, how could i assign the height of the list item row to a fixed metric?

Comment: post the code of list view also

Comment: your linear Layout Height android:layout_height="match_parent" Plz try

Comment: I just pasted your code in my eclipse and set my own image in place of yours , its looking fine occupying 60dp height so check size of your image and post code of list adapter

Comment: you assign layout weight to 1 in textview. for more info
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight

Comment: put your code here that you tried. your xml look fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have looked the source code for LayoutInfalter's infalte function , if the root is null, then the LayoutParams is not generate for this view, and a default layoutParams will be used when attached to others. If root is set, then inflater will generate and set a LayouParams for this view. However, the attachToRoot cannot be set to true, cause the View get will be added to the adapter view soon.

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filtered_trip_row, parent,false);
```

This solved my question .

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed my too tall row item for my custom `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

Alright alright, no need to panic it happenes.

in your getView of adapter, just write this code before returning the view.

```
// Just reset the layout parms before return
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            60*3); // put proper dp pixel conversion here, in hdpi it 3px = 1dp

    view.setLayoutParams(params);
    return view;
```

Comment: You answer did solve my question, but I think the better way propablly is using View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filtered_trip_row, parent,false); so the layout attributes set in xml will take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Please check 'parent' parameter to null while inflating your row,

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filtered_trip_row, null);
```

Instead try this,

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.filtered_trip_row, parent);
```

Now try to set your height inside getView.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I have looked the source code for LayoutInfalter's infalte function , is the root is null, then the LayoutParams is not generate for this view, and a default layoutParams will be used when attached to others. If root is set, then inflater will generate and set a LayouParams for this view. However, you answer is partially right, cause in listAdapter's get view , you can't set the attachToRoot to true(default is true when root is set), it will throw an exception

Comment: You can make LayoutParam's instance and set to your view

Comment: When I set the "null" to "parent" as you suggested, it crashed my app and gave me a `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView` error. Before, I was having the same problem. My list row is too high, but adjusting it in the `xml` does nothing.